# Open new modal after close current modal (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I use a Bootstrap modal to display a pdf

I would like that when the user closes the modal (by clicking on close or clicking outside the mdoal) a new modal opens

For open my Pdf on modal I use this code :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary show-pdf" title="exemple" href="./parcel.php">PDF</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(a){a.twModalPDF=function(b){defaults={title:"Parcel",message:"Fail",closeButton:true,scrollable:false};var b=a.extend({},defaults,b);var c=(b.scrollable===true)?'style="max-height: 1020px;overflow-y: auto;"':"";html='<div class="modal fade" id="oModalPDF">';html+='<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">';html+='<div class="modal-content">';html+='<div class="modal-body" '+c+">";html+=b.message;html+="</div>";html+='<div class="modal-footer">';if(b.closeButton===true){html+='<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>'}html+="</div>";html+="</div>";html+="</div>";html+="</div>";a("body").prepend(html);a("#oModalPDF").modal().on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){a(this).remove()})}})(jQuery);


  $(function(){    
    $('.show-pdf').on('click',function(){
      var sUrl = $(this).attr('href');
      var sTitre = $(this).attr('title');
      var sIframe = '<object type="application/pdf" data="'+sUrl+'" width="100%" height="500">Aucun support</object>';
      $.twModalPDF({
        title:sTitre,
        message: sIframe,
        closeButton:true,
        scrollable:false
      });
      return false;
    });
  })

</script>
```

It's work well and for open the new modal I have this, but they don't work ...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Finish" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Attention</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ....
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg col-xs-12 margin-bottom" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <form action="./forms/success.php" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="saveDispatching" value="1" class="btn btn-lg btn-default col-xs-12">Yes</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.modal').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#oModalPDF')
            .modal('hide')
            .on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $('#Finish').modal('show');

                $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal'); // Remove the 'on' event binding
            });

    });
</script>
```

How I can do ?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to organize your code like this:

```
$(function(){    
  $('.show-pdf').on('click',function(){
  var sUrl = $(this).attr('href');
  var sTitre = $(this).attr('title');
  var sIframe = '<object type="application/pdf" data="'+sUrl+'" width="100%" height="500">Aucun support</object>';
  $.twModalPDF({
    title:sTitre,
    message: sIframe,
    closeButton:true,
    scrollable:false
  });

  $('#oModalPDF').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('e', e);

    $('#Finish').modal('show');

    $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal'); // Remove the 'on' event binding
  });

  return false;


});
```

My JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/xb3apwws/)

**UPDATE**

If you resolving handler script tags with PHP, you could try this approach.

You still have `$('#oModalPDF').on('hidden.bs.modal', ... )` handler inside modal initialization, but also you have:

`window.dialogOnCloseHandler = null;`

that stores your callack after close event. It is a **bad pattern** to store something in global scope. So you should refactor that callbacks storage for your case.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

window.dialogOnCloseHandler = null;

$('.show-pdf').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var sUrl = $(this).attr('href');
  var sTitre = $(this).attr('title');
  var sIframe = '<object type="application/pdf" data="'+sUrl+'" width="100%" height="500">Aucun support</object>';
  $.twModalPDF({
    title:sTitre,
    message: sIframe,
    closeButton:true,
    scrollable:false
  });

 $('#oModalPDF').on('hidden.bs.modal', window.dialogOnCloseHandler);

});
```

})

Your after close event callback script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   window.dialogOnCloseHandler = function (e) {
      console.log('e', e);

      $('#Finish').modal('show');

      $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal'); // Remove the 'on' event binding
  };
```

});

Here you just update `window.dialogOnCloseHandler` property with you handler.

JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/xb3apwws/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much ! But Can I disassociate the two JavaScript code? In fact I want add a condition (php) for open the new modal (like that : 

`if ($countNumber == 0 and $countCheck == 0) 
        { echo " <script> ...</script>" }` )

Comment: If you use only jQuery and Bootstrap, I think you need wrap all your script code in $(document).ready(function(){}) insead of $(function(){}); And then you need put your <script> tags in correct order.

Comment: My website is in Php so when the page load I have a condition set so I only want this cmportement for one condition, for other I don't want open a second modal, Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you ! I tried this and it work :
`<script type="text/javascript">
...
...
    <?php if (mycondition) {?>
      $('#oModalPDF').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        console.log('e', e);

        $('#Finish').modal('show');

        $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal'); // Remove the 'on' event binding
      });

      <?php } ?>
....
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be listening for the `hidden.bs.modal` event before hiding the modal. Right now you're hiding the modal and then start listening for the hidden event which won't be triggered as the modal is already hidden.

```
$('.modal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#oModalPDF')            
        .on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $('#Finish').modal('show');

            $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal'); // Remove the 'on' event binding
        })
        .modal('hide');

});
```

I don't know if you're animating anything, but if not you won't even have to listen to an event, you could simple hide the modal and open a new one on click:

```
$('.modal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#oModalPDF').modal('hide');

    $('#Finish').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this completely but I believe you do not need to add the code

```
$('#oModalPDF').modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#Finish').modal('show');
    $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal'); // Remove the 'on' event binding
});
```

inside the `$('.modal').click` event as you have written.

```
$('#modalID1')    //the modal id which upon closing triggers the next modal
    .on('hidden.bs.modal'){
        $('#Finish').modal('show');
    }
```

What this will do is that as soon as the previous modal closes, it will trigger the show event of the next modal.